# VSCODE - Open New External Terminal - Opens in wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCODE i use the command "Open New Integrated Terminal"

I expect the cmd terminal to open at my project path or the path where the file is located.

But the terminal always opens at c:\windows

How can i make the terminal open at the directory where the file is located?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the integrated terminal in Visual Studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487445/how-to-change-the-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thanks, But this answer explains how to open a different terminal than cmd but does not explain how to make the terminal open at the project / script directory

Comment: From inside VS Code built-in terminal, cd into your project folder/directory and enter command: code -a .

Note period at end.

This will open your current directory/project folder without opening a new window.